# jQuery: How to delete the first <div> child inside an element? Or next previous brother <div>?

Tags: jquery

Assume I have a html code similar to

```
<div class="foobar" ....>
   <p>
   <div> first stuff</div>
   <div class="sec"> second stuff </div>
   .....
</div>
```

1.) How can I delete the first `<div>` element INSIDE the `<div>` parent element with class="foobar"?

2.) How can I delete the first `<div>` brother element BEFORE the `<div>` element with class="sec"?

If possible suggest a jQuery code. Otherwise JavaScript is acceptable too.

Thank you
Peter

Explained in the previous text

Comment: Please share what you have tried (and apparently didn't work), and focus on one question only, as now it is too broad (with 2 questions). Finally, add what you have researched so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delete the first  element inside the  parent element with class="foobar":

Using jQuery:

```
$('.foobar > div:first').remove();
```

Using plain JavaScript

```
var parentElement = document.querySelector('.foobar');
var firstDivElement = parentElement.querySelector('div:first-child');
parentElement.removeChild(firstDivElement);
```

This code selects the first  element that is a direct child of an element with class "foobar" and removes it.

Delete the first  brother element before the  element with class="sec":

Using jQuery

```
$('.sec').prev('div').remove();
```

Using plain JavaScript

```
var secElement = document.querySelector('.sec');
var firstBrotherDivElement = secElement.previousElementSibling;
firstBrotherDivElement.parentNode.removeChild(firstBrotherDivElement);
```

This code selects the  element with class "sec", then selects its immediately preceding sibling  element and removes it.

These JavaScript examples perform the same tasks as the jQuery examples, but without relying on the jQuery library.

Comment: Greta! Thank you

One more related question:

Is it guaranteed that only within the current parent is searched (and returned)?
So if there is no first child or if there is no previous <div> brother nothing should happened.

Especially no element outside of parent should be returned

Comment: Yes. It works. Mark question answered!